# can't access slim homepage using localhost

Tags: composer-php, slim

I've installed composer.php, then run `php composer.phar require slim/slim "^3.0"` command and next i want to access myslimsite but it wont get open. localhost/myslimsite didn't woked

Comment: Did you setup you webserver and set document root?

Comment: Yes. did everything

Answer (score 0):

Just install the [Slim Framework 3 Skeleton Application](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton):

```
composer create-project slim/slim-skeleton [my-app-name]
```

Alternatively, you can also try this [Slim tutorial](https://gist.github.com/odan/d2b889c350aa2ea0ff8e5ca93ce588a2).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running it on your local webserver you can try to launch

```
php -S localhost:8888 -t public public/index.php
```

inside the slim framework main directory.

Then you'll be able to access your webservice from

```
http://localhost:8888
```

---

if you want to use the local webserver you'd need 2 htaccess file:

put **the first one** inside your slim directory with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^$ public/     [L]
   RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

then put the **second one** inside the public directory with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Hope this help.